# closing Cursor in SQLite database explicitly, needed or not needed?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I understand that a after a database is closed, the cursor becomes "invalid", does that also close the cursor at the same time?  Does that avoid having to do what is shown below?

example 1

```
 public void String getResultsAndReturnString() {
      String result = "";
      SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, projection, null, null,
                    null, null, null);
      cursor.close();  <-- explicit cursor close example one
      db.close();
     return result;
  }
```

example 2

```
public void Cursor getResultsAndReturnCursor(){
   SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, projection, null, null,
                    null, null, null);
   return cursor;
}

public void closeOut(Cursor cursor, SQLiteDatabase dataBase){
     cursor.close();   <-- explicit cursor close example two
     dataBase.close();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cursor isn't closed in the strict sense by closing the database (it's still there and you can perform operations on it), but as you know, closing the database makes the cursor useless.  You should close cursors explicitly after you're done using them for a number of reasons:

1) As you noted, after closing the database, any remaining cursors become "invalid," and cannot be relied upon for accurate data;

2) You will see warnings in LogCat;

3) You risk memory leaks if you maintain a reference to a cursor; and

4) It's simply good programming practice to close out resources that you no longer need.

Comment: How a cursor mapped to a system resource? What is the db instance itself then? I believe db is the mapped os resource but couldn't be sure about cursors. Closing cursor attempts to close the underlying db ( may or may not success ), so what's the logic here? Any ideas?

Comment: @zgulser I think the assertion about "[c]losing cursor attempts to close the underlying db" is incorrect. A cursor is a discrete set of results from the database and not the database itself. Therefore, closing a cursor has no effect on the database.

Comment: Hi, that's why I saw in the stack trace. It doesn't necessarily to close it though - it only attempts to close it as far as I understand. Plus, it is always advised that to have a null check prior to closing db which this assertion might be the reason, I suspect.